# Lua userdata alignment

Tags: memory, lua, alignment, allocation

How does lua_newuserdata align the allocated memory? Does it depend on malloc/calloc, or does it do it's own thing? Is there any way to guarantee alignment without having to add code for this?

Writing alignment code myself isn't a problem, but if it's not needed then I'd rather not, of course.

Comment: It seems that Lua uses standard C realloc() function and doesn't perform additional alignment.

Comment: Thanks, I'll write my own alignment code then.

Comment: Actually, Lua *does* its own alignment for the payload of a userdata. You can't get more alignment than the allocator gives you, but you could get less. See [the definition of userdata](http://www.lua.org/source/5.3/lobject.h.html#Udata) and in particular of [`L_Umaxalign`](http://www.lua.org/source/5.3/llimits.h.html#L_Umaxalign). The latter also allows you to change that alignment.

Answer (score 3):

All memory allocation in Lua is done throughout a [user-supplied allocator](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#lua_Alloc) given when you create a state with [`lua_newstate`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#lua_newstate).

If you use [`luaL_newstate`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#luaL_newstate) instead of `lua_newstate`, then Lua uses [a memory allocator based on `realloc`](http://www.lua.org/source/5.3/lauxlib.c.html#l_alloc).

Comment: It's worth adding that the allocator callback is given a hint about what the memory is used for.  See http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#lua_Alloc.  In particular: "When ptr is NULL, osize encodes the kind of object that Lua is allocating. osize is any of LUA_TSTRING, LUA_TTABLE, LUA_TFUNCTION, LUA_TUSERDATA, or LUA_TTHREAD when (and only when) Lua is creating a new object of that type."